# Lenovo G580 install fails

Tags: installation, laptop, lenovo

I'm trying to get a Lenovo g580 with Windows 7 to dual-boot with Ubuntu 12.04.3. It has UEFI so Wubi didn't work for me.

Then I found some advice to install from a liveDVD so I shrank the Windows C: partition to make space for Ubuntu.

The next step in the advice was to load the liveDVD and use GParted to merge the unallocated space to the D: drive (because my Lenovo laptop has already got the Max 4 drives) but no matter what I did, I couldn't get the drives to merge & I'm finding it very complicated in the advice on the net.

Can anyone tell me a step-by-step guide of getting Ubuntu to dual boot on a Lenovo laptop which has "one key recovery".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a Lenovo laptop and I haven't problems with Ubuntu. A official tutorial : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

It's good to use official tutorial because It's very important to install correctly it.

Comment: What drive did you install Ubuntu onto? In my laptop it has the maximum number of drives & there is no unallocated space. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: please open Ubuntu in live mode from cd or usb, press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+ `T` to open terminal, type `gparted`, press `Enter` and make screenshot with `PrtSc` key(Print Screen key) after loading ends. And finally upload the screenshot and post it here.

Comment: It's need for me, else I can't help you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/awmyvonmk7h6okh/Screenshot%20from%202013-11-25%2020%3A19%3A20.png

Comment: i hope you can see that screenshot. let me know if not

Comment: I regrete but you need to reinstall windows and delete all data. I think that partition LENOVO  and LENOVO_PART are for Recovery key, I delete it and the Recovery key doesn't work. Do you want to keep this function?

Comment: Ive been looking at a few other questions that have been answered and it looks like there is no easy way to install ubuntu on a lenovo G580. I can't reinstall windows because lenovo dont give you any install CDs. Im not really that knowledgeable so I think I might have to leave installing it on this machine. Its a shame its hard to install. I enjoyed using it on a virtualmachine. Thanks for your advice and trying to find a solution

Comment: Ok! It's your choice. I use only Ubuntu in Lenovo Z580 and it works ok. Use the solved mark for close this question.